# Which branch am I on?

Tags: release-management, do-release-upgrade

After doing a `do-release-upgrade -d` about a month ago, I switched, as intended, to the development branch (`-d`) of Ubuntu 17.10. Now, after its final release, I would like to confirm that I am back to the stable branch again. Which command would I use?

Comment: Try `lsb_release -a`.

Comment: This gives me information about the version, but not about the branch.

Comment: Does it say "Development branch"? If not, then it's not.

Comment: Finally, after the development branch of 18.04 became available, I was able to test the `lsb_release -a` command (in a VM). It works. If you put this inside a proper answer, I will mark it as correct and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. If it has references to `artful` then you're on 17.10, and will continue to get updates (for 9 months) on that stable release.

Comment: What would I have if I was on the development branch of 17.10?

Comment: There is no "development branch" as such now 17.10 is now released. Soon there will be a new development branch if you like, which will become 18.04.

Comment: So are you saying that in the `sources.list` I would find references to `artful` regardless whether I am on the "development branch" (that is prior to the release date or after the release date if the machine was not upgraded) or on the "stable branch"? Then how does `sources.list` help me with my problem?